# Task :segment_analytics-react-native:writeDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

I'm struggling with this problem when I execute with CLI, which is "npm run android".

Here is my log.

```
> Task :segment_analytics-react-native:writeDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':segment_analytics-react-native:writeDebugAarMetadata'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/Users/-/app/node_modules/@segment/analytics-react-native/android/build' when creating directory '/Users/-/app/node_modules/@segment/analytics-react-native/android/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/debug'

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

Please save me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove node_modules folder and fire a command

```
1. cd android
2. ./gradlew clean
3. cd ..
4. npm install or yarn install
5. npx react-native run-android or yarn android
```

I hope it works for you.